# Python: Mocking DateTime Issues

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime, timedelta

Here is my Python method:

```
for time in (timedelta(hours=3), timedelta(minutes=30)):

    delay = (datetime.now() + time).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    payload = json.dumps({
        "channels": [
            "accountID-{acct_id}".format(acct_id=account_id)
        ],
        "push_time": delay,
        "data": {
            "alert": "Test Push",
            "m": "12345"
        },
    })

    try:
        requests.post(
            "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
            data=payload,
            headers={
                "X-Parse-Application-Id": settings.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID,
                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": settings.PARSE_REST_API_KEY,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        )
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Here is my test:

```
@patch("requests.post")
def test_send_push_notifications_to_parse(self, post_mock):
    post_mock.return_value = {"status": 200}
    mailing = Mock()
    mailing.name = "Foo Name"
    mailing.account_id = 12345
    mailing.mailing_id = 45

    payload = json.dumps({
        "channels": [
            "accountID-12345"
        ],
        "push_time": "2014-03-04T15:00:00",
        "data": {
            "alert": "Test Push",
            "m": "12345"
        },
    })

    send_push_notification_to_parse(mailing.account_id, mailing.mailing_id, mailing.name)

    post_mock.assert_called_with(
        "https://api.parse.com/1/push",
        data=payload,
        headers={
            "X-Parse-Application-Id": settings.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID,
            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": settings.PARSE_REST_API_KEY,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    )
```

The test fails because the POST request is inside of a loop where the `datetime`object changes. How can I patch the `datetime` object to make my test pass?

Answer (score 3):

Just mock `datetime` *in your module*:

```
@patch("your.module.datetime")
@patch("requests.post")
def test_send_push_notifications_to_parse(self, post_mock, dt_mock):
    # set datetime.now() to a fixed value
    dt_mock.now.return_value = datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8)
```

You bound `datetime` in your module with an import, and the above `@patch` decorator will replace that object with a mock.

If you need to test against multiple values, you can set the [`dt_mock.now.side_effect` attribute](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.side_effect) instead; a  list will cause the mock to return values one by one from that list on sequential calls, a method lets you produce a new value each time `datetime.now()` is called as needed.

Comment: Hmm.. I keep getting this error: `<MagicMock name='datetime.now().__add__().strftime()' id='4393253584'> is not JSON serializable` the method that I am testing is inside of a background job

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: then `datetime.now()` didn't return what you wanted to return (an actual `datetime` value). It returned a `MagicMock` instead, and that then has `__add__` called on it, etc.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: usually, that means that you didn't mock the right `datetime` name.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone stumbling on this old question like me can use [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) that Lets your Python tests travel through time(like Interstellar:))